# page loading indicator yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I try to add loading indicator. In view add

```
     $this->registerJsFile('js/loading_indicator.js', [
        'depends' => ['yii\web\JqueryAsset']
    ]);
    $this->registerJsFile('js/loading_indicator.js');
<img src="http://dkclasses.com/images/loading.gif" id="loading-indicator" style="display:none" />
```

In css this

```
`#loading-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}`
```

In js this

```
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
    $('#loading-indicator').show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    $('#loading-indicator').hide();
});
```

But when page loading there is no indicator.  When I remove this `style="display:none` indicator always on page.

Comment: Please print alert message in ajaxSend. Then check its working or not

Comment: @HirenBhut I add this `$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
    alert('alert');
     $('#loading-indicator').show();
})` its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the js file in the head section of your html page:

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/loading_indicator.js', [
    'depends' => ['yii\web\JqueryAsset'],
    'position' => View::POS_HEAD,
]);
```

Remove the second call to registerJsFile.